# Database error when using CiviCRM admin UI: "Row size too large"

Tags: error, database, webserver

I'm helping on a site that is on a different server than usual and see this error regularly in the back end when trying to complete various tasks (e.g. clear caches, run database updates, etc.)

`[debug_info] => TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_menu [nativecode=1118 ** Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.]`

The site is mostly working, but as mentioned many tasks error out and the above shows in the debug log. What could cause this?

Comment: are they using multiple languages?

Comment: No, just English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also see https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31644/225 where the suggested fix is:

```
 ALTER TABLE civicrm_menu ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Then rebuild the menus

Comment: Thanks! I just commented out the `innodb_strict_mode=0` setting as a test and performed this ALTER -- and it seems to fix it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions from various folks on chat include the following settings in `my.cnf`:

- `innodb_log_file_size` ([may be too small by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25373052))
- `innodb_large_prefix=true`
- `innodb_file_format=barracuda`

I changed those and was still having issues. This setting fixed it for me (and may be due to the site running on MariaDB?).

- `innodb_strict_mode=0`