# CiviCRM Log Viewer 1.2 not working after upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6 to 4.7

Tags: upgrade, configandlog

CiviCRM Log Viewer 1.2 not working after upgrade from CiviCRM 4.6 to 4.7, what do I need to change for it to work again?

Error message (I took out root dir info)
Unable to read entries from logfile at /wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM.d1b4fb7408ae18b71a1d53b3.log

There is no such file in the "files/..." directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It was related to menus not being rebuilt.

The menus had to be rebuilt, but before that the row format on the civicrm_menu table had to be changed to dynamic.  Somehow during the database copy from production to test, the test table row format was changed to dynamic so didn't have the issue.

THE FIX:
ALTER TABLE civicrm_menu ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
Then rebuild the menus ( I used CiviCRM Admin Utililties -> Rebuild Menu)

Error was:
    [debug_info] => TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_menu [nativecode=1118 ** Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.]
    [type] => DB_Error

Comment: Nice - looks like it also addresses https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/31632/225

Comment: Could someone explain how to issue such sql commands for civicrm via ssh? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @ajasper you would need to access your database - mysql maybe?. How you do that depends on how your server is setup. `sudo mysql ` will work if its setup for local access without password but otherwise you will need to look into your servers setup. If you're using something like cpanel you might have GUI for executing SQL queries.