# No CiviCRM Menus on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I just installed CiviCRM v5.16.2-wordpress on a WordPress site running WP 5.2.2 Everything seems to be working but I do not have any menus on the top bar. I can get to the Administer CiviCRM screen and have tried different menubar positions under Display Preferences, but still nothing. I am sure I have messed up some setting, but am brand new and have no clue. Thanks for any help.

[image]

**UPDATE 8-22-2019**

Jon G. I followed your suggestions.

I cleared the cache and received this message: [image]

Still no menus.

Checked the Resource URL setting and it is correct.

Tried a different theme, no luck.

Went to the Developer's Tools in my Firefox browser and saw mostly 200s and one 404. Here is a screenshot of that 404 error
[image]

Looking at the error details, I went to the location of the file in my hosting File Manager and the file is there (along with several others)
[image]

Suggestions for what else I can try?
Thanks.

**UPDATE: 8-23-2019**

Well, I've been trying different things. I went into Debugging from the Adminster CiviCRM screen, turned on debugging and switched to Development mode. When I saved those changes, the menubar appeared. If I switch back to Production mode they disappear.

Comment: The same thing happened to me with my subdomain sandbox after I upgraded to 5.16.4 from 5.15.1

Comment: Is this related at all? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/31644/26

Comment: @GeorgeLozier, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Laryn-CEDC.org not sure. The issue is not a big enough concern for me to take too much time to delve into it, but thanks for the input.

Comment: I have been having the same issue for months now. I thought it must be a known bug but was surprised it was not fixed on subsequent Civicrm releases. This issue is there for all my new sites. I just did a clean new installation with latest WP and latest Civicrm and still the same. Additionally for contribution pages Live links (eg : https://myURL/civicrm?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1 returns the default Civicrm Page. I have to use short codes for everything. I am on a IIS 6.2 server with PHP 7.3.7. The bigger problem is none of the forms are submitting data as wel

Answer (score 5):

I would try clearing caches (click **Cleanup Caches and Update Paths** on the admin menu).  I would also check your Resource URL to make sure it's correct (click **Resource URLs** on the admin menu).

I would also try using one of the built-in themes (e.g. "twentynineteen") to rule out a badly-behaving theme.

Finally, I would try bringing up your browser's Developer Tools (press "F12"), heading to the **Network** tab, and reloading the page.  If you see any *404*, *403*, *500* errors - really, anything besides a *200* - please update your question with those details.  Also note that you'll want to do a hard refresh of the page in between the first two steps - that's **Ctrl-Shift-R** on Windows/Linux, and **Cmd-Shift-R** on a Mac.

**UPDATE:** Looking at the request URL in your screenshot, that looks pretty squirelly.  I very much doubt thaat's the correct URL.  That says to me that there's probably something wrong with your Resource URL.  Is it possible that you're using a symlink ("alias") in your file path?  If so, try to fix any paths defined either in **Administer » System Settings » Directories** or in `civicrm.settings.php` to use the equivalent non-symlinked path.

Comment: Jon G. - Thanks for responding. I edited my question with what I found.

Comment: @jeff_in_ky I updated my answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jon G. That makes sense. I've concluded that it has something to do with file paths. I'll play around with it when I get a chance and see if I can nail it down. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I am not sure what is actually causing the problem, but I believe it is related to file and resource paths. The site that I installed CiviCRM on is a subdomain. I use that site as a Sandbox to test things before going to the main site. I installed CiviCRM on the main WP site at our domain and the menus appear fine. On the Sandbox site, since I can put the site into Development mode and the menus appear, I am not going to spend anymore time on getting to the root of the issue.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I 'fixed' this on my sandbox WordPress installation by:

1. Uninstalling CiviCRM.
2. Doing a fresh install of the latest CiviCRM version.
3. Installing my extensions.
4. Restoring a copy of my production database.
5. Upgrading the database.
6. Clearing the Caches and rebuilding the menus.